# Why am I getting an ObjectDisposedException when exiting the form whilst it's fading in or reopening the project cycle?

Tags: c#, forms

I am writing an application in C# that will display a report for different projects, the application allows the user to either select a specific project by office, team and project, or it allows the user to cycle through all the projects for a given team.

Displaying a single project is fairly straight forward the application will just open up another form and display the relevant information. The project cycle on the other hand works on a timer, after 60000ms the application will close the last form and reopen another (a new form object is created each time) with the next project being displayed. There is also another timer that will fade out the form after 59800ms.

The issue I'm having is that when the user tries to reopen the project cycle after exiting or exiting the cycle during the form's fade in, it will throw:

> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Cannot access a disposed object.

The error is thrown in this method:

```
private async void FadeIn()
{
    this.Opacity = 0;
    while (this.Opacity < 1.0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        this.Opacity += 0.05; //exception is thrown on this line
    }
    this.Opacity = 1;
}
```

The user exits the report cycle by pressing the ESC key, which triggers this method:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
            {
                Program.MainForm.cycleTimer.Stop();
                Program.MainForm.fadeOutTimer.Stop();
                Program.MainForm.currentReport = 0;
                Close();
                Program.MainForm.forms.Clear();

                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
```

This is the method that the project cycle timer triggers:

```
private void CycleProjects(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (forms.Count > 0)
        {
            forms[0].Close();
            forms.Clear();
        }

        int projectCount = projects.Rows.Count;
        if (currentReport == projectCount)
        {
            currentReport = 0;
        }

        Form2 cycleReport = new Form2();
        cycleReport.Project = "AND p.Project = " + projects.Rows[currentReport]["Project"].ToString();
        cycleReport.Office = (cmbOffice2.SelectedIndex == 0) ? 1 : 2;
        cycleReport.AmberThresholdFrom = Convert.ToInt16(txtAmberFrom.Text);
        cycleReport.AmberThresholdTo = Convert.ToInt16(txtAmberTo.Text);
        cycleReport.RedThreshold = Convert.ToInt16(txtRed.Text);
        forms.Add(cycleReport);
        cycleReport.Show();

        currentReport++;
    }
```

I have tried simply hiding the form and allowing the CycleProjects method to dispose of the form, but that threw the same exception in the same place. I have also tried creating a `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel the task within the FadeIn method when exiting the cycle, but I had no luck with that, the exception was still thrown.

I simply don't understand why this exception is getting thrown when I'm creating a new Form object each time the CycleProjects method is called.

Comment: It looks like the timer is still trying to access the form after it's been closed. Not sure why that it though. The call to `Stop` should halt the timer instantly.

Comment: @ChrisF that's what I was thinking, I will try implementing a check for the timer being stopped.

Comment: The [example on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) calls `Dispose` after the `Stop` and there is a `Disposed` event that fires. You could investigate that.

Comment: @ChrisF The timers are being stopped successfully, but I don't see any harm in disposing them and then creating new timer objects each time the start cycle button is clicked. Just not sure about the likeliness of that being the fix.

Comment: Well, it must take a finite time for the timer to stop and if in that time you close the form I can see how it *could* cause the problem you're seeing - but it does seem odd to me too.

Comment: @ChrisF I have disposed of the timers and it has fixed the issue for exiting after the fade in has happened, but the error still occurs when exiting during, must be something else causing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the timer is still trying to access the form after it's been closed. Not sure why that it though. The call to `Stop` should halt the timer instantly. However, the [example on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) calls `Dispose` after the `Stop` and there is a `Disposed` event that fires.

I can see that there is a (more than) theoretical chance that you are closing the form before the timer has had a chance to stop - especially if it's on a small time interval - so if you wait until the `Disposed` event has fired then you'll know that it's save to close the form.

Move your `form.Close();` call into `timer.Disposed` event handler.

The other thing you should look at is using a different timer - `System.Timers.Timer` is not the best thing to use when dealing with the UI. For one thing, it's resolution (i.e. the minimum time between calls) is not that great.

Comment: You'll have to tell him that System.Timers.Timer is evil and should never be used to display UI.  Many problems with it, but calling Stop() certainly does not guarantee that the Elapsed event handler won't be called.

Comment: So System.Threading.Timer would be the better choice when working in a multithreaded environment and with UI?

Comment: @TheHornyDonut. Yes. That would be a better choice.

Comment: @ChrisF Ended up using Windows.Forms.Timer as I need to be working within the same thread as the UI. I have figured out why the exception is thrown when exiting during the fade in, that's due to the form being closed whilst running a while loop, I could avoid this by using a try/catch, but would prefer another way around it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent this error from occurring, and to exit the fade-in loop when the form is closed/disposed, you could modify your `FadeIn()` method to something like the following:

```
private async void FadeIn()
{
    this.Opacity = 0;
    while (this.Opacity < 1.0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        // Check to see if form is disposed, and if so, exit loop:
        if ((this.IsDisposed) || (this.Disposing))
        {
            return;
        }

        this.Opacity += 0.05;
    }
    this.Opacity = 1;
}
```

This will prevent *System.ObjectDisposedException* from being thrown while attempting to set the opacity of a form which has been disposed.

Alternatively, you can try and catch the *System.ObjectDisposedException* and exit the method using the following pattern:

```
try { this.Opacity += 0.05; }
catch (ObjectDisposedException) { return; }
```